# Ruby and Netbeans problem

Tags: ruby, netbeans, netbeans6.5

I'm reading a file line by line in a simple program and when I print the the lines to the screen the last line can't be seen at the ouput window in Netbeans 6.5.1 IDE on Windows XP but when I run the program directly from the command line as "ruby main.rb" there is not a problem (i.e the last line can be seen).I'm using Ruby 1.8.6.Here is the entire code :

```
File.open("songs.txt","r") do |file|
  file.each do |line|
    print line
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work better if you use `puts` which will append a newline terminator if there is not already one at the end of the line, forcing a buffer flush.

Answer (score 1):

I've never run across this before myself, but my guess would be that your final line doesn't have a trailing line break, so the Netbeans console isn't flushing the line.  Try adding [`$stdout.flush`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M002303) at the end of the program and see what happens.

By the way, you can simplify this code slightly by rewriting it using [`foreach`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M002268):

```
File.foreach("songs.txt","r") do |file|
  print line
end
```